# Displaying response to user from bot in different color in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using Bot framework to build bot.

I am using the following line to send the response to user:-

dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity);

In teams the response from bot to user in black text.

Do we have a feature to send text to user in different Color(like red, blue...).

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's  no option to color a normal text message, but have you looked into sending a card of some sort (e.g. Adaptive Card)? In that case you set styles, sizes, background images, and so on. For instance, if it's an "alert" type of message you could send have a relevant image on the card.

Comment: Bear in mind though, whatever you choose in terms of these (backgrounds, styles, etc.) should be tested for different themes in Teams (Dark, Light, High Contrast) and may also render differently on desktop vs. mobile (e.g. something in *italics* on one form factor might not render the same on another), so you should test all these scenarios where possible

Comment: Do you mean changing the color  of the actual font, or highlighting phrases?

Comment: Yes @Hilton, Since I couldn't find any option I'm using adaptive card with text box element but even the adaptive card is supporting six colors.

Comment: Yes, formatting, especially colours, is quite limited. As I mentioned above, I think the idea with this is to support all theme/device/screen scenarios best. What do you need the colours for, out of interest? Is it something like "alert" vs "warning"?

Comment: @Chekrii There is no way you could add colour to the plain text. You need to use Adaptive cards which has colours property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following some of the conversation in the comments above, here's a more complete answer:

There's no way to set the color or style of the text in a normal "text" message - to do that, you need to use an Adaptive Card. Adaptive Cards don't have "real" colours in the normal sense (like you don't choose "red" or "blue" or hex code or anything like that), but they support use cases like "good" or "warning", and the environment in question (i.e. Teams in this case) will render that appropriately, based on the user's theme (so it will have an appropriate way to display "warning" in light theme, dark theme and high contrast theme).

You can see more about this [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextBlock.html). Aside from that, Adaptive Cards also support some limited markdown format for things like **bold** and *italics* - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features).

As a final option, you can use the backgroundimage property of the card to represent certain features. For instance, in a "success" scenario you might want to have a background image that represents that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to remap the color values given (`good`, `warning`, `attention`) to different colors? Or are we bound by the values that are defined by microsoft?

Comment: In short, no - those colours are left up to the end platform with, for instance, Teams rendering them one way, Outlook another, etc., but they're not able to be remapped. Bear in mind, the client tool needs to handle, for instance, theme changes (e.g. dark, light, and high contrast), device form factors, etc. - so best left up to the platform to deal with.